# Conditional or filter argument with matching ID across multiple rows R

Tags: r, tidyverse

For each ID, I would like to firstly search movement column for "climb", if climb is present it should only remain in the dataframe if "jump" OR "hop" is also present in movement for that ID.

**Example data**

```
ID = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4)
Movement = c("walk", "run", "skip", "hurdle", "walk", "hurdle", "climb", "walk", "run", "climb", "jump", "climb", "hop", "skip")
dat = data.frame(ID, Movement)
```

**Example outcome**

```
ID2 = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4)
Movement2 = c("walk", "run", "skip", "hurdle", "walk", "hurdle", "walk", "run", "climb", "jump", "climb", "hop", "skip")
dat2 = data.frame(ID2, Movement2)
```

I've been playing around with `group_by` and `filter` / `ifelse` but not getting the outcome I would like. As always, appreciate any support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to the other answers but uses `sum()`. Here, for each `ID` you exclude (`!`) columns meeting the criteria that `Movement == "climb"` and, for the same `ID`, no other `Movement` is `"jump"` or `"hop"` (i.e., `sum(Movement %in% c("jump", "hop")) == 0)`)

```
dat %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(!(Movement == "climb" & sum(Movement %in% c("jump", "hop")) == 0)) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 13 x 2
      ID Movement
   <dbl> <fct>   
 1     1 walk    
 2     1 run     
 3     1 skip    
 4     1 hurdle  
 5     2 walk    
 6     2 hurdle  
 7     3 walk    
 8     3 run     
 9     3 climb   
10     3 jump    
11     4 climb   
12     4 hop     
13     4 skip
```

Comment: Answer chosen over @Maximillian because when applied to my full data set it gave the shortest script. Both other solutions solved the problem - appreciate the support.

Comment: @akrun - as above. Thanks for your input, always nice to see alternative routes to the same outcome.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want all rows removed where Movement is "climb" and "jump" and "hop" are not in Movement for that ID. I think this is the shortest solution using dplyr:

```
dat %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
filter(!(Movement == "climb" & !("jump" %in% Movement) & !("hop" %in% Movement)))
```

Remember to ungroup after transformation :)

Answer (score 2):

After grouping by 'ID', create a logical condition to check whether both 'climb', 'hop' or 'climb', 'jump' are present in 'Movement'.  Based on the logical column, we remove the 'climb' for IDs that doesn't have the combination

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
    group_by(ID)  %>%
     mutate(i1 = !(all(c("climb", "hop") %in% Movement)|
         all(c("climb", "jump") %in% Movement))) %>%
     filter((i1 & Movement != "climb")|!i1) %>%
     select(-i1)
# A tibble: 13 x 2
# Groups:   ID [4]
#      ID Movement
#   <dbl> <fct>   
# 1     1 walk    
# 2     1 run     
# 3     1 skip    
# 4     1 hurdle  
# 5     2 walk    
# 6     2 hurdle  
# 7     3 walk    
# 8     3 run     
# 9     3 climb   
#10     3 jump    
#11     4 climb   
#12     4 hop     
#13     4 skip
```